# Python PIL image grab crashes

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

Hello i'm experimenting with PIL, opencv2 and keras. But I encountered some weird problem which is the image grabbed from my screen is crashing when it's being shown by opencv.

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as backend
import keras
class MC():
    def Screen(self):
        last_time = time.time()
        while True:
            # 800x450 windowed mode
            printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,450)))
            print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))

            last_time = time.time()

            cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

test=MC()
test.Screen()
```

The screen is just gray and saying not responding.
[image: The screen]
Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You need `cv2.waitKey(1)` after `cv2.imshow()`
- Your `cv2.cvtColor()` parameter is wrong too, though it will work. PIL grabs as RGB and OpenCV uses BGR, so you should actually use `cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR`